# Proving uniqueness of solution to 1-D Wave equation without energy conservation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, mathematical-physics, wave-equation

We have a homogeneous string of length L fastened at its ends, performing small transverse motion in a vertical plane. The tension in the string is assumed sufficiently large for gravitational forces to be neglected . The motion is then governed by:

> - $ c^{2}\frac {\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}} = \frac {\partial^{2} u} 
>      {\partial t^{2}}$
> - $u(0,t)= u(L,t)=0$, for all $t\geq 0$ and  $u(x,0)= f(x) ; \frac {\partial u}{\partial x} (x,0)=g(x)$

Now, the problem of concern:

> Suppose we have found solutions $u(x,t)$ and $v(x,t)$ to the IBVP.
>   Show uniqueness for the solution, i.e. $u(x,t)=v(x,t)$ for all $x$ and $t$, using the integral:
>
> $I(t) :=\int_0^L (w(x,t))^2 dx $,
>
> where $w(x,t)= u(x,t)-v(x,t)$.

Further, any insight into where this integral comes from would also be of interest to me.

My argument:

Note that by linearity, $w(x,t)$ satisfies the wave equation and all boundary-/initial conditions are homogeneous.

Differentiating twice under the integral (by Leibniz' rule), integrating by parts and applying the wave equation, gives $I''(t)=0$.
The Identity theorem applies and we have $I'(t)=const.$ . But $I'(0)=0$, by the initial conditions for $w(x,t)$, so $I'(t)=0$. The identity theorem applies and we have $I(t)=const.$.
Using the boundary conditions for $w(x,t)$ we obtain $I(0)=0$ and hence $I(t)=0$.
Since the integrand is strictly non-negative ( and assumed to be continuous) we must have $w(x,t)=0$. 
Uniqueness follows immediately and my argument is complete.

I would greatly appreciate, if someone would check that my argument works.
Thanking in advance!

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail regarding your conclusion that $I''(t)=0$? I don't agree that it follows immediately from substitution via the wave equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is flawed.
Let $I(t) = \int_0^L (w(x,t))^2 dx $, thus $\frac{dI}{dt} = \int_0^L2w(x, t) w_t(x, t) dx$. Differentiating again yields
$$\frac{d^2I}{dt^2} = \int_0^L 2w(x, t) w_{tt}(x, t) + 2w_{t}^2(x, t) dx $$

Using the wave equation, $c^2 w_{xx} = w_{tt}$ will **not** result in $I''(t) = 0$.

Just for completeness and further reference, you can use the energy function
$$E(t) = \int_0^L c^2w_x^2 + w_t^2 dx$$
to prove the uniqueness theorem. By differentiating, you can easily see that 
$$\frac{dE}{dt} = \int_0^L w_t ( w_{tt} - c^2w_{xx}) dx = 0$$
thus $E = \mathrm{const} = 0$. It follows that $w(x, t) = 0$.

Comment: I try but i simply can't prove the "you can easily see" step. It must be true. So can someone help and prove that? My last try was to consider a simple function $w(x,t) = sin(x -ct)$, which is a solution of the wave equation. Then I calculated $w_x$ and $w_t$ and squared. Then I differentiate it inside the integral with respect to time. The result is not zero. It is proportional to $sin^2(x-vt) - cos^2(x-vt)$. Thanks